# How can a mage gain quintessence besides gathering at a node?

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension, quintessence, mage-20th-anniversary

In M20 there doesn't appear to be many given methods for recharging quintessence beyond finding a wellspring or finding some tass. (Unless you are at prime 5 in which case you can just make nodes whenever you need quintessence) So I wanted to ask. How can a mage gain quintessence other than wellsprings or nodes?

Things I came up with. (Not sure how viable they are so I would appreciate debunking or confirmation.)

Forces 3+Prime 3 to convert energy to quintessence. (Like electricity)

Life 3+Prime 3 to convert life into quintessence(Like flowers or moss)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be found in the **Sacrifice** section of *How Do You* DO *That?* The most common is **Heart's Blood,** which used to be called "burning your Pattern" in older editions. With Prime 1, you can deal yourself a level of damage to add a point of Quintessence to your Pattern. This damage is unhealable by any means that aren't mundane. (*How Do You* DO *That?*, p.50) Prime 2 + and Matter 2 let you sacrifice significant objects, and Prime 3 + Life 3 let you do it to living things.

Comment: Thank you. Could you also confirm if force 2 and prime 2(Or 3) could be used to generate quintessence from electricity?

Comment: @MaikoChikyu No. Drawing Quintessence from Forces requires Prime 4. (M20, p.521) It's easier to pull from Patterns, which hold Quintessence naturally, than from Forces or Ephemera.