# Can people generate quintessence through prayer?

Tags: world-of-darkness, mage-the-ascension, quintessence

I have been thinking about various quintessence sources and I was thinking on how a mage could reliably generate quintessence on a weekly basis without a node. The idea I came up with was a pastorship.

In MtA the idea of belief being power is emphasized quite a bit.

So what I want to ask is: Is it possible to make use of people's prayers in order to generate quintessence (or tass) and which spheres would be involved in such a quintessence production?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Drawing quintessence from the ambient environment calls for Prime ••••, and the prayers of the faithful could make a fine paradigmatic reason for that to work — and flavor the resonance appropriately. (This is detailed in "Tapping the Wellspring" in M20's **How Do You DO That?**, page 43, but all versions of *Mage: the Ascension* allow for drawing quint from "nothing" at this level of Prime.)

Comment: So the answer is "yeah, sure, whatever"? Like it could be a church service, but could equally well be a weekly D&D game. Using prayer gives no advantage here -- it's just one of many acceptable fluff reasons.

Comment: I mean, yes, but sincerely. If you were a mage whose paradigm centered on the idea that other worlds were accessible through imagining them through roleplay, the process might be similar. In Mage, the notion that tools and practices are a lens through which your will is focused is key to the setting.

Comment: Depending on the nature of the prayer, you could also potentially draw Quintessence from prayer with a lower Prime score, if the prayer involves some form of sacrifice or mortification of the flesh.

Comment: @nick012000 That's certainly true. There's more on that here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/183612/how-can-a-mage-gain-quintessence-besides-gathering-at-a-node

Answer (score 6):

## So long as that prayer includes sacrifices

See "How Do You Do That?" p.50

With matter 2 and prime 2 you can burn valuable objects for their quintessence. One can imagine a church that demands poverty, and makes people burn objects of great value at the behest of the church during service to fuel their head mage to grant the mage lots of power.

Prime 3 allows you to tap willing blood sacrifices. You can take a small amount of life force from willing victims, including church goers, granting yourself a regular supply of power.

Answer (score 1):

I have found several rotes that deal with this situation and I felt they justify a direct answer.

Spinning Thread
Allows the Weaver to pull esoteric things, such as “the
shriek of a thrice cursed ifrit” and convert it into a
physical form, Tass.

While not neccessarily from a service one could use it to convert things like 'Prayer of a desperate mother.

Another thing would be
Legions Life
Requiring a group of at least twenty people who have
bonded closely (such as with common military training),
the Mage can use this bonding to siphon off
Quintessence from the group rather than from
individuals, not taking much from any single person.
For every twenty people in the group, the Mage can gain
one Quintessence without causing any harm. The Mage
can pull a maximum of one Quintessence per success
on this rote. This draw may be done once per day

Which again could be used to draw quintessence from people that bonded through worship.

Finally An Uncompromising Commitment to Excellence

Targets of this procedure work harder than they’ve
ever worked before. Successes are spent first up to the
highest willpower of all targets, then to duration. Each
success after that decreases difficulties in a single
Attribute + Ability pool by 1. For every hour spent in
this state, each target takes a level of aggravated damage
from the physical and psychological strain of working
beyond capacity. If one of the workers dies, the
Technocrat gains 5 points of Primal Energy.
Targets can roll Willpower at difficulty 8 to resist each
time they suffer damage or are asked to do something
blatantly self-destructive or Nature-defying. Successes
accumulate until they have more successes than the
highest Willpower, at which point they break free. Sleepers must spend a Willpower point each roll, but do not gain an automatic success

This could be used to make people keep praying fervently till they die which would generate quintessence.